# How can I make another button highlighten on popup window on Mac by using Keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, popup, shortcut

[image]

On the above shown asking popup window on Mac, how can I select another button (left button) by using keyboard.
Without clicking mouse button, I want to make left button highlighten.
Is there any shortcuts?

Comment: In dialog boxes with two options like this, the escape button will usually perform the secondary action. I'm not aware of any shortcuts that will allow you to change the focus of the button, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

After reading Tricon's answer, I got the way!!!

Just see the following shortcuts.

Preferences -> Keyboard -> Keyboard & keyboard input (I don't know the correct English menu, I'm using Korean "탭이 초점을 이동하는 방식 변경 (^F7) )

Once you do ^F7 (In case of mac book, Control + fn + F7) on a popup window, you can travel over buttons on any popup windw!!!

Thank you Tricon for giving me clue :)

Answer (score 47):

Go to Preferences -> Keyboard. At the bottom, turn on "All controls" under "Full Keyboard Access".

The alternate option will be highlighted with a blue ring. Hitting space will activate this. If there are multiple options, hitting tab will alternate between them.

Comment: Finally ! Thank you. To toggle this mode without using the Preferences menu, use Ctrl+F7 (requiring the 'fn' button).

Comment: Slightly different steps to reach that option in Yosemite: Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts tab.

Comment: yea lets think different - why not to choose it with tab/arrows and confirm it with return key as would every human beeing expect - lets make it harder! yay - just a small hint - this setup is not needed/available on OS X 10.10(.5)

Answer (score 24):

For English/Mac OSX 10.10:

Go to Keyboard in System Preferences, and then select 'All controls'. Space will select the alternate option if two options. If more than two options then tab will alternate between them.

[image]

PS: I would much rather the option of using arrow keys and enter. Interested to know if anyone knows how to hack this?

Comment: Yeah, I'd also love to have arrow keys and enter, or type the underlined letter, or any of those old ways.

Answer (score 2):

In Catalina in `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` press `Use keyboard navigation to mve focus between controls`. Then you can use Tab to highlight another button and use Space to actually press it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Ventura, you need to enable the "Keyboard navigation" switch in the Keyboard System Settings:

[image]